# Not able to open video files using OpenCV VideoCpature java class in Android

Tags: opencv, android

I am trying to load couple of AVI files from phone storage. Sample paths -

/storage/emulated/0/Download/received_files/video1.avi
/storage/emulated/0/Download/received_files/video2.avi

```
 VideoCapture vc1 = new VideoCapture();
 VideoCapture vc2 = new VideoCapture();

 if (!vc1.open(video1)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not open the video file1");
 } else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Video1 loaded");
 }

 if (!vc2.open(video1)) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Could not open the video file1");
 } else {
    Log.i(TAG, "Video2 loaded");
 }
```

Needless to say it always returns "Could not open ..." message.

File paths are correct, I am able to create File object using above paths and File.exists() returns true.

I am using OpenCV 3.2.0. Am I missing something?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OpenCV for Android supports only MJPEG codec in AVI container hence it will not open any video encoded with any other codec. (source [opencv.org](http://answers.opencv.org/question/126732/loading-video-files-using-videocapture-in-android/))

FFMPEG may be used to support other codecs.